# Using `this` as a pointer to derived class in a base class in CRTP

Tags: c++, this, crtp

I am trying to use CRTP to register all live (created but not yet destroyed) instances of some class. This works for me well:

```
template <typename T>
class Registrable {
  public:
    void _register(T* p) { instances_.insert(p); }
    void _unregister(T* p) { instances_.erase(instances_.find(p)); }
    static const std::set<T*> & instances() { return instances_; }
  private:
    static std::set<T*> instances_;
};

template <typename T>
std::set<T*> Registrable<T>::instances_;

class Class : private Registrable<Class> {
  public:
    using Registrable<Class>::instances;
    Class() { _register(this); }
    Class(const Class &) { _register(this); }
    Class(Class &&) { _register(this); }
    ~Class() { _unregister(this); }
    void function() { }
};

int main() {
  Class c;
  auto upc = std::make_unique<Class>(c);
  std::vector<Class> vc(5);
  for (auto i : Class::instances())
      i->function();
}
```

**EDITED:**

Better would be not to care about registering and unregistering of instances in derived classes. Solution according to @Jean-BaptisteYunès and @Aconcagua:

```
template <typename T>
class Registrable {
  public:
    static const std::set<T*> & instances() { return instances_; }
  protected:
    Registrable() { instances_.insert(static_cast<T*>(this)); }
    Registrable(const Registrable &) : Registrable() { }
    Registrable(Registrable &&) : Registrable() { }
    ~Registrable()  { instances_.erase(instances_.find(static_cast<T*>(this))); }
  private:
    static std::set<T*> instances_;
};

...

class Class : public Registrable<Class> { ... }
```

However, **I am also not sure whether this type of casting is safe**. Especially, if `Class` would additionally derive from another class via multiple inheritance.

The answer of @amc176 claims, that I can assume that the cast will be successful, but I would prefer to be sure. According to @Aconcagua's comment, I can be sure, just it's not in the answer.

Comment: By the way, you might it find interesting in a virtual Registrable's destructor to unregister, too (if not yet done) - for the case of bad usage in a sub class...

Comment: Why not using ctor/dtor in `Registrable` to call private register/unregister? Thus you will ensure that every registrable would be registered.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That came to my mind already, too... -Elegant, but you lose one degree of freedom - what, if the user of a derived class explicitly wants not to register some of the instances?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I wasn't sure about safety of the cast. If it's ok, as Aconcagua claims, it would be the best solution for me. Working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gM4XOrPeiqBA7i0d

Comment: @DanielLangr Consider the rule of five, though - as you did with your derived class already (partially, at least)...

Comment: About move semantics: A moved object is no longer in a valid state! You might consider unregistering the moved object immediately when being moved, so iterating over the instances won't catch up on the invalid objects. Destructor then might look as this (shortened): `auto i = find(); if(i != end()) erase(i);`.

Comment: @Aconcagua Good note about move/copy ctors. As for moved-from objects, why shouldn't they be in valid state? If you move from objects of, e.g., `std::vector`  `std::string`, you can still perfectly use them.

Comment: @Aconcagua As I wrote, I want to register all _created but not yet destroyed_ objects. Of course, one can modify `Registrable` to register _created but not yet destroyed or moved-from_ objects as well. It's a matter of what one wants.

Comment: @Aconcagua if the user doesn't want to register then he doesn't subclass `Registrable` that's all. Semantic is clear of `Registrable` is clear.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès But then user can't register *any* instance any more... Another, similar scenario: user wants to *temporarily* unregister some class instances...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Don't get me wrong - I don't blame your approach being bad or just inferior, in contrast, it has its fine advantages, too! Just as it is, every advantage comes with a drawback, and I'm just hinting to it... Admitted, Daniel clarified in the meanwhile that he doesn't need/want such flexibility.

Comment: @DanielLangr Admitted, incorrect wording. In General, state is valid, yes, but you need to expect them in *any* state... For STL components, C++17, 20.5.5.15§1: "[...] Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state."

Comment: @Aconcagua For me, if you want optional registration then an external collection is better, so you don't need to carry all the registration stuff in every object.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès *"Need to carry"* - well, as is, not much to carry... Still, good point from view of design. That would then exactly be the original template (with explicit parameter), just not inherited from... Good candidate to make it final *then* (if flexibility desired).

Answer (score 2):

[`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) makes no runtime checks to ensure the cast is completely safe. Anyway, as you know the type `T` will be a derived class of `Registrable<T>`, you can assume the cast will be successful.

In fact, in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) it's mentioned that this cast is typically used when applying CRTP (referred as [`static polymorphism`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Static_polymorphism) in the link).

Comment: Thanks, and will it work even with multiple inheritance? Working example with CRPT: https://wandbox.org/permlink/hHVtFmoRXYRoxMVu. It seemingly works, but not sure whether static polymorphism handles these cases as well.

Comment: @Aconcagua There is nothing wrong with public inheritance, if it only exposes `instances` member function, which needs to be exposed to users as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr I see - then I misinterpreted your question, thought you wanted to get this right for non-public inheritance explicitly... "if it only exposes `instances`" - then you might want to make the (un-)register functions protected, though... BTW: I wouldn't use function names with leading underscores in public/protected interface...

Comment: @DanielLangr To be a tiny little bit more explicit: `static_cast` *will* get the type right even with multiple inheritance - provided the object you apply the cast to really is of that type, and this is what *you* have to assure when using this type of cast (you did in the given case...). Casting can fail badly with `reinterpret_cast`, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree, the reason was that any class, which might have its own `register` member function, can derive from `Registrable`. And its more unlikely that it will have `_register`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Actually, it won't have a `register` function anyway - that name is still a reserved keyword...

Comment: @Aconcagua Right, then, e.g., `reg` instead of `register` or any other name. I wanted to prevent such a name mismatch. As Jean-BaptisteYunès proposed, avoiding such functions and using ctor/dtor of `Registrable` is much better solution for me here.